# How to assign value to <td> using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm inserting a new row using ajax append() to a table from mysql database from backend.

```
$(".item_ho").append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.product_name + "</td><td>" + data.product_code + "</td></td><td id='price_value'>" + data.price + "</td></td><td>" + data.product_desc + "</td><td>" + data.barcode_number + "</td><td>" + " <input type='number' name='total_qty_value' value='1' size='5' id='product_qty_value' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-barcode_number='" + data.barcode_number + "'> " + "</td><td>" + "<a id='remove_row' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-barcode_number='" + data.barcode_number + "'>x</a>" + "</td>" + "<td id='total_price'></td>" + "</tr>")
```

I can access each of the row  and **i'm able to change the value** of it at the init stage. Like this: At first i'm finding the `<tr>` from that particular table. And then for each of the  i'm accessing them using **eq(*row_number*)** and doing some addition for **amount** and the **price** and saving the *result* to a  variable **$total_amount** `<td>` which is then assigned to a row like this `$tds.eq(8).text($total_amount);` below is the code **this one works**:

```
var table = $("table  tbody");
table.find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    var $total_amount
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        amount = $tds.eq(3).text(),
        price_html = $tds.eq(6).html(),
        price = $(price_html).val();
    total_amount_tab = $tds.eq(8).text();
    $total_amount = parseInt(amount) * parseInt(price);
    $tds.eq(8).text($total_amount);
});
```

Now next i'm trying to assign `eq(8).text()` with a different variable which holds a different value `change_total`. 
But i'm not able to update  **$tds.eq(8)**. I've tried this *below doesn't seem to work:*

```
$(document).on('change', '#product_qty_value', function() {
            // document.getElementById('get_qty_value').value = document.getElementById('product_qty_value').value;
            document.getElementById('get_qty_value').value = $(this).val();
            $parent_html = $(this).parent().html();
            $hey = $($parent_html).val();
            $($hey).val($(this).val());
            //calculating the price.

            // getting the row data
            parent_data = $(this).parent().parent().html();
            product_price = $(parent_data).eq(3).text();
            qty = $(this).val();
            change_total = product_price * qty;
            alert(change_total);
            $main_test = $(parent_data).eq(8).text(change_total);
```

**This next line of code doesn't work ( it does't update eq(8).text())**

```
 $main_test = $(parent_data).eq(8).text(change_total);
```

so if i use this  `$('#total_price').text(change_total);` (**where #total_price is the id of eq(8)**) it updates only the first row even tho i change the other row input box value, because i know i'm using the 'id'. I cant update $(this).row!

**Any idea why this is not working**

```
$main_test =  $(parent_data).eq(8).text(change_total);
```

> What i want to do in brief is update the value of each row from an
>   input and store the value in the #total_price of that same row.

Comment: You are taking **parent_data** as html content. It should be dom reference.
Change Line of code from `parent_data = $(this).parent().parent().html();` to `parent_data = $(this).parent().parent();`

Comment: this gets me the value for the current data. $main_test =  $(parent_data).eq(8).text();

Comment: `yt.fn.init [prevObject: yt.fn.init(1)]` this is the console.log output i get. If i try to alert it i get [object Object ].  **If i chnage too parent_data = $(this).parent().parent();** i can't access the values like this `product_price = $(parent_data).eq(3).text();`

Comment: I still didn't get what i'm dong wrong here, when i use this  `$(parent_data).eq(3).text();` i get the output of the text which is currentlu there. But i cannot assign a new value to it like this  `$(parent_data).eq(8).text(change_total);` i don't understand where i'm going wrong. A little help would really be helpful.

Comment: Are you adding the row to the table on every successful ajax request?

Comment: yes i am. thanks :D